# What is the best way to develop a shopping site, that others can use

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'd like to develop an ecommerce site where I could allow others to sell items, things like pictures, videos, flash, etc. I want to be able to keep a percentage, and pay the rest back to the seller.

Is there anything available, DotNetNuke, etc. that would do this or help get this started. If not what's a good way to approach this with the goal to avoid upfront time and cost.

I'd like to think there would be some revenue that could be reinvested over time, so might grow into something that has some cost after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) if you want something with a minimum of development time, otherwise, if you have some development budget, why not take a look at [Spree](http://spreehq.org/).

Comment: I like both Shopify and Spree, thanks for telling me about them, unfortunately neither support "downloadable" products.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DotNetNuke, or another similar framework if you have additional content that you need to include other than the shopping.

If you went with DotNetNuke, you could look at the Catalook store which I believe supports your desired format for selling.  It isn't perfect, but it does work, eventually with a little experience.  Otherwise ASP .NET Storefront might have what you need as well, either in a DNN based version or their standalone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WordPress, or another similar framework if you have additional content that you need to include other than the [shopping](http://thefashionmart.in).

If you went with WordPress, you could look at the Catalook store which I believe supports your desired format for selling. It isn't perfect, but it does work, eventually with a little experience